# Why was Fiendfyre contained in the Room of Requirement?

Tags: harry-potter

Given the intensity of Fiendfyre as seen in *The Deathly Hallows*, how come the Room of Requirement contained the fire, and prevented it from consuming the whole castle?

Comment: Not sure (that's why I don't make a full comment), but I guess that's because the room of requirement is not on the same plan as the school. It kinda exist either elsewhere and the door is just a portal, or in another parallel world. That would also explain why it takes exactly the form and the content needed.

Answer (score 3):

The Room of Requirement can be considered a dimension unto itself consisting of several linked spaces making up individual rooms, kind of like a beehive. The door only appears after a specific process so it can be understood that it acts like a gate.

Therefore, when the door was closed, the Fiendfyre spell was effectively sealed in the "Room of Hidden Things", while the other rooms are safe from it and can be accessed normally.